# Combination Chart Problem in Displaying Xlabel and its Correct Quantity?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, combinations, visualization

| StockCode | Quantity | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22326 | 1248 | 3643.20 |
| 15036 | 1164 | 853.32 |
| POST | 1124 | 21181.00 |
| 20719 | 1021 | 854.85 |
| 21212 | 1002 | 551.10 |
| 22585 | 936 | 1033.20 |
| 22423 | 881 | 9866.55 |
| 22629 | 877 | 1633.35 |
| 22554 | 872 | 1438.80 |
| 22961 | 818 | 1186.10 |

I have a table called **df_ger_top10** like this and I want to visualize a combination chart including revenue and quantity of each stock code. However, when I visualize them in a chart, the quantity shown for bar chart is wrong, and I don't know why.
It seems like the xlabel is modified when I add revenue line because when I remove the line graph of revenue, it becomes normal. Here is my code for the combination chart, which shows wrong quantity of each stock code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.barplot(x= df_ger_top10.StockCode,
            y= df_ger_top10.Quantity, 
            color='#004488',
            ax=ax1)
for p in ax1.patches: 
    height =p.get_height()
    ax1.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
        height + 3,
        '{:1.0f}'.format(height),
        ha="center", fontsize=12)
ax1.set_title('Top Selling Categories and Revenue',weight='bold',fontsize=16)
ax1.set_ylabel('Quantity',weight='bold',fontsize=13)
ax1.set_xlabel('Stock Code', weight='bold',fontsize=13)


sns.lineplot(x=df_ger_top10.StockCode, 
             y=df_ger_top10.Revenue,
             color='g',
             marker="o",
             ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylabel('Revenue',weight='bold',fontsize=13)

ymin, ymax = ax2.get_ylim()
bonus = (ymax - ymin)/40
for x, y, name in zip(df_ger_top10['StockCode'], round(df_ger_top10['Revenue']), round(df_ger_top10['Revenue']).astype('str').replace('\.0', '', regex=True)):
    ax2.text(x, y + bonus, name, color = 'g', weight = 'bold', ha='right')
plt.show()
```

[image: My visualization]

Comment: 1) don't post data as an image. Are we supposed to type in it manually? 2) in your code, you have a lot of undefined variables and unimported modules

Comment: @PaulH sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this because the lineplot and barplot order your x variables differently. You can simply convert your StockCode to category:

```
df_ger_top10.StockCode = pd.Categorical(df_ger_top10.StockCode)
```

And run your code, and you should get:

[image]